# Can I get exception when operation return 0.#INF

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, exception

Is there any setting in MS VS2008 to generate exception if operation return 0.#INF? Using usual debugging doesn't help me because I can't figure out where it's occured.

Answer (score 2):

You can use _control87 to enable division-by-zero exceptions.  Like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <float.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    _control87( ~_EM_ZERODIVIDE, _MCW_EM );
#endif
    double value = 1;
    value /= 0;   // kaboom
    return 0;
}
```

Use this *only* to diagnose the bug.  Changing the FPU control word is very destabilizing to libraries that expect the FPU to have its default initialization.

Answer (score 0):

There is an **Enable Floating Point Exceptions** in the **C/C++->Code Generation** of your apps properties